# Cannot use import statement outside a module in /node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs, node-modules, es6-modules

I'm in the process of migrating some node packages which has become quite a headache.

Currently this is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  //These are the updated dependencies and Jest configurations
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^4.0.2",
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^3.2.3",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.7.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.2.3",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.9.7",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.14",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "nest-winston": "^1.4.0",
    "p-all": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.1.5",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.5",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.2.3",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-mock": "^27.4.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      ".module.ts",
      "main.ts",
      "env-var-names.ts",
      ".d.ts",
      ".types.ts",
      ".e2e-spec.ts"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "resetMocks": true,
    "resetModules": true
  }
}
```

When I try to run Jest, I get the following error relating to `/node_modules`

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/{username}/{project_directory}/node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import type {
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:8:12)
```

So within our team, we've been able to fix it by changing a part of the Jest configuration from:

```
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "src"
],
```

To so:

```
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
],
```

We also had to change our import paths back to relative. This gets rid of the error and is working fine, however we are a bit stumped as to why this works? Does anyone have any insight they could share?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you don't have Typescript set up for your build.

Answer (score 18):

I faced the same issue today and was totally mad that mongoose v5 was running without any problems and v6 gave me this freaking error. Luckily after 2-3 hours of tilting at windmills I found a solution (works for me at least).

All I had to do was adding literally one word to `jest.config.js`.

```
// before
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']

// after
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src']
```

I think that problem occurred because of the location of `bson.ts` file. It lays under `/node_modules/mongodb/src/bson`, the path has `src` in it so I suppose it caused conflicts with jest config where we match `src`. Usage of `<rootDir>` fixes out problem cuz it eliminates paths that don't start in root directory and testing works fine.

Comment: Thank you! You are rock man, saved my day!

Comment: You are such a legend!

Comment: You are a king.

Comment: Legend! I've spent 4 hours and no hope until this.

Answer (score -3):

It seems that you didn't enable the es6 import/export. Add this to your package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what solves the issue (have tried). My es6 imports/exports work fine but for some reason, the error is coming from node_modules.